# ValueError: option names {'--browser'} already added

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

**pytest** - I've been trying to run a command in the pycharm terminal to execute a pytest script. When tried to run the code its displaying error. **raise ValueError("option names %s already added" % conflict)
    ValueError: option names {'--browser'} already added**
    enter code here
    Command from terminal - py.test-v -s test_file.py --browser firefox

```
**test_file.py**
 import pytest
    def test_command_line_methodA(oneTimeSetUp, setUp):
         print("Running method A")

     def test_command_line_methodB(oneTimeSetUp, setUp):
          print("Running method B")

**conftest.py**
 import pytest

   @pytest.yield_fixture()
       def setUp():
           print("Running method level setUp")
           yield
           print("Running method level tearDown")


    @pytest.yield_fixture(scope="module")
      def oneTimeSetUp(browser, osType):
         print("Running one time setUp")
         if browser == 'firefox':
            print("Running tests on FF")
           else:
             print("Running tests on chrome")
            yield
            print("Running one time tearDown")

            def pytest_addoption(parser):
                 parser.addoption("--browser")
                 parser.addoption("--osType", help="Type of operating 
    system")

            @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
                 def browser(request):
                    return request.config.getoption("--browser")

             @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
                 def osType(request):
                    return request.config.getoption("--osType")
```

Comment: Is your code formatted in the question as in your file on your computer? What is your version of pytest? Correctly formatted, your code run perfectly on my computer with python 3.7.4 and pytest-5.1.2.

Comment: Yea the code is formatted the correct way. There are two files conftest.py and test_file.py with the same code mentioned above. 
The python 3.7.3 & pytest version -5.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error. But your indentation is the same than the one you post, I think the matter comes from it. With the code below, it works fine:

*conftest.py*:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def setUp():
    print("Running method level setUp")
    yield
    print("Running method level tearDown")


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def oneTimeSetUp(browser, osType):
    print("Running one time setUp")
    if browser == 'firefox':
        print("Running tests on FF")
    else:
        print("Running tests on chrome")
    yield
    print("Running one time tearDown")


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")
    parser.addoption("--osType", help="Type of operating system")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def osType(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--osType")
```

*test_file.py*:

```py
import pytest
def test_command_line_methodA(oneTimeSetUp, setUp):
    print("Running method A")


def test_command_line_methodB(oneTimeSetUp, setUp):
    print("Running method B")
```

I also change `yield_fixture` into `fixture` because it is [deprecated](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/yieldfixture.html)